# Help with error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: visualforce

I have created a Visualforce page, which has a commandbutton on it. The code for this is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Disease__c" extensions="myExtension" title="Button">
<apex:commandButton value="Notify" styleClass="options" action="{!notifyPatients}"/>
</apex:page>
```

So, in my Visualforce page I call a method "notifyPatients" in my extension "myExtension".

The extension class looks like this:

```
public with sharing class myExtension {

    public Disease__c d {get; set;}

    public myExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        d = (Disease__c) controller.getRecord();
        }
    }

    public void notify() {
        emailHandler.sendNotification(d);
    }
}
```

And above I then call a method in my emailHandler class to send out a notification.
This looks like the code below:

```
public with sharing class emailHandler {
  public static void sendNotification(Disease__c d) {
  EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'NotifyPatients']; 
  [...]

  }
}
```

And now, when I click on my button in the visualforce page, I get the following error message, which is displayed in the Salesforce user interface:

```
List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Error is in expression '{!notifyPatients}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page buttonsPage

An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the code for the `notifyPatients` method as well

Comment: I didn't add all the code, because when I added the line: 'EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'NotifyPatients']; 
', I realised that it needs to say: DeveloperName, and not Name in my query.

Comment: Was that the issue? The error is referring to a SOQL query that is not returning any rows. The SOQL in your comment above would cause that issue if now rows were returned

Comment: yes, it seems that was the issue. I guess since it couldn't find the template, no rows were returned? Anyway, that's the only thing I changed and then it worked :)

Comment: exactly. Ive added an answer with some more detail

Answer (score 2):

The `List has no rows for assignment to SObject` error is referring to a SOQL statement that is trying to store the result as a single SObject but no rows are being returned.

The code below will cause that error because there is no `EmailTemplate` records being returned:

```
EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body 
                              FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'NotifyPatients'];
```

Based on your comments on the question the above SOQL should of been using `DeveloperName` rather than `Name` in the `where` condition as shown below.

```
EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body 
                             FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'NotifyPatients'];
```

A more robust solution that handles these scenarios in a more user friendly manner is shown below

```
List<EmailTemplate> templates = [SELECT Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body 
                             FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'NotifyPatients'];
if (templates.size() > 0) {
    // Do something 
} else {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.Error,'No EmailTemplates found.')
        );
}
```